# Android chucker dependency not found

Tags: android, debugging, dependencies, chucker

I am trying to integrate the chucker library into my Android project. I have added require dependencies and repositories in my project. My app-level build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        **maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }**
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        **maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }**
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My dependency declaration is as follow:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    **debugImplementation 'com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library:3.2.0'**
}
```

After running my project it givems me following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library:3.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/ChuckerTeam/Chucker/library/3.2.0/library-3.2.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/ChuckerTeam/Chucker/library/3.2.0/library-3.2.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/ChuckerTeam/Chucker/library/3.2.0/library-3.2.0.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/ChuckerTeam/Chucker/library/3.2.0/library-3.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Application is not able to resolve this dependency.

Comment: Facing same issue